# why Sometimes effects (in one thread) don’t become visible to other threads?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency

I'm reading Paul Butcher's "Seven concurrency models in seven weeks", it gives sample code "puzzle.java" in chapter 2.2:

`ThreadsLocks/Puzzle/src/main/java/com/paulbutcher/Puzzle.java 
public class Puzzle { 
  static boolean answerReady = false;
  static int answer = 0;
  static Thread t1 = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
      answer = 42;
      answerReady = true;
    }
 }; 
static Thread t2 = new Thread() {
   public void run() {
     if (answerReady) System.out.println("The meaning of life is: " + answer);
     else System.out.println("I don't know the answer");
    }
 };
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
   t1.start(); t2.start(); t1.join(); t2.join();
 } }`

So here is a racing condition.

Then it says,

> Imagine that we rewrote  run()  as follows:

`public void run() { 
while (!answerReady) 
  Thread.sleep(100); 
System.out.println("The meaning of life is: " + answer); 
}`

> Our program may never exit because  **answerReady**  may never appear to
>   become true.

May I ask why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106591/do-you-ever-use-the-volatile-keyword-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgive me if I failed to explain this clearly in the book. I'll try again here :-)

The first thing that you need to recognise is that the loop in `t2` will only exit if `answerReady` becomes `true`. And the only thing that sets it to `true` is `t1`.

So, in other words, for `t2` to exit, it needs to see a change in memory made by `t1`.

The problem is that the JVM makes *no guarantees whatsoever* about whether changes made by one thread are visible by another thread *unless* the code is correctly synchronised.

As this code is not correctly synchronised (there are no locks in use whatsoever) the JVM makes no guarantees about whether `t2` will ever see the change to `answerReady`. So the loop may never exit.

Comment: Although JVM doesn't guarantee but can there be any reason variable will not be written to main memory even after long time (as question says it may not be visible forever) like in this program no other processing is happening?

Comment: Thanks Paul, now I got it. Btw, brilliant book!

Comment: In practice, it almost certainly will eventually be written to memory, @Vipin. But there's no guarantee, so you can't rely on it.